# How to Create a Custom "Look Ahead" Field Formula?

Tags: ms-project

I am very new to MS Project and I am struggling to create a Look-Ahead formula for a flag field in a master project file (collection of sub projects). I can't seem to get even the simplest formula to work-

> IIf([Start]>[Status Date],Yes,No)

Everything looks as if it is defaulting to "No" and I am so new to MSP that I don't know why.

[image: Custom Flag Formula]

[image: Master Project]

I'm almost sure that I am misunderstanding something fundamental, I just need someone to point out where I am being a dunce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a linked project structure, then the sub-projects reside in separate files.  In that case you need to open each source file directly (not as a subproject) to modify and save the custom field formulas.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I needed to update each source file _and_ assign a Status Date to each. My master had a Status Date but none of my sub projects had them (thus all the "No"s across the board).

I also found a VBA script [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d7fb11fb-93d4-4897-946b-4a22d77a0f8c/status-date-in-master-projects?forum=projectserver2010general) to update the Status Date of all sub projects.